# Vagrant curl connection refused while provisioning

Tags: vagrant, couchdb

I have CouchDB running on a Vagrant box. I want to create the database when provisioning the box. To create the db, I use curl to make a `PUT` to 127.0.0.1:5984/foo. If I do this manually, no problem. SSH-ing into the Vagrant box and running the command works. Running the command on the host machine works. But if I have the provisioning script run the command, I get this error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5984: Connection refused`. What is the problem?

Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5984, host: 5984, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/provision_vagrant.sh"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 thing:

First, when you run your command after you ssh'ing into the box, you will run the command as `vagrant` user but when you run your provisioning as you shown you actually run the command as root; so to respect what you did when ssh'ing make sure to run with `privileged: false` argument as follow:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "./scripts/provision_vagrant.sh"
```

consider this when you write your shell script as if you run as root, you dont need the `sudo`

Second, when starting a process such as couchdb it takes a bit of time (few seconds to a minute depending hardware) to completely start and be available, this is totally fine and its the same for most process (mysql, apache) so when running the `curl` from your script it might be running while couch is starting up and not fully available.

The easiest is to sleep just enough so that the server is up - the most sophisticated version is to read the output log file until it says it has started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately provisioning as vagrant produces the same result.

Comment: are you sure your couchdb service is running on 5984 at the time of your provisioning runs ?

Comment: it's not running. i `sudo stop couchdb`, modify a config file, and then `sudo start couchdb`. but when i `netstat -tulpn`, it doesn't show any process on `:5984`.

Comment: ok so you should look at the log or the error when you start the process - or it takes some time to start and you cannot push right in the second after it starts - make a sleep (3 to 5 minutes) after you start couchdb and see if it runs after

Comment: `sleep 3s` and then `curl...` works. if you post this as a new answer, i'll accept it. also, do you know if the required delay indicates something is wrong?

Comment: thanks, I edited the answer - no the delay is totally fine, most app requires a few seconds to complete their startup and its not automatic, the script runs all commands and forks the new process creation so it runs the next command that the process is not completed